# GCM success count is greater than total app installed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a android application installed on total 2 millions of devices, out of which 1.5 million is uninstalled (According to google play).
When I sent a push notification to all devices(including uninstalled) in 1000-1000 of chunks, the collective response from GCM server is->
success .9 million and failure 1.1 million.

I am not getting why GCM send .9 million as success while my current app install is .5 million?

Comment: May I know why it is down-voted.I didn't get any google support on this. Google itself say to fire a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution as below :

Google statistics never say 1.5 million is uninstalled, it only says .5 million is currently installed by device.

By digging more, I found the google definition of *current installs by device*: "Active devices where the application is currently installed, excluding any devices where the application was uninstalled **or any devices that are no longer active**".

Hence my remaining .4 millions(.9-.5) are installed but inactive and still served by GCM.

[image]